# What are the $T$-invariant subspaces for the following shift operator $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let $T: \mathbb F^n \longrightarrow \mathbb F^n$ be the shift operator $:$

$$T (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = (x_2,x_3, \cdots , x_n,0).$$

Let $W_k : = \{x \in \mathbb F^n : x_j = 0,  \forall j > k \}$. Show that these are the only $\mathbb F [X]$ submodules of $V$ where $V = \mathbb F^n$.

I know that the $\mathbb F [X]$ submodules of $V$ are precisely the $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$. So I have tried to solve this question by first showing that all the $W_k$'s are indeed $T$-invariant.But I find some trouble in proving the converse part i.e. the only $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$ are $W_k$'s. I found that for $k \geq i$, $T^k (e_i) = 0$ and for $k  < i$, $T^k (e_i) = e_{i-k}$.I also proved that if $m  < n$ then $(a_m X^m + a_{m-1} X^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0).(e_n) = (a_m T^m + a_{m-1} T^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0 I)(e_n) = (0,0,\cdots,0,a_{m},a_{m-1}, \cdots , a_0)$ and if $m \geq n$ then $(a_m X^m + a_{m-1} X^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0).(e_n) = (a_m T^m + a_{m-1} T^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0 I)(e_n) = (a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, \cdots , a_0)$.

Now how can I proceed? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a $T$-invariant subspace $W$, set

$$ j = \min \{ k \, | \, W \subseteq W_k \}. $$

Note that $W_n = V$ so this is well-defined. Then we have $W \subseteq W_j$. Let us show that in fact $W = W_j$.

If $j = 0$, we are done. Otherwise, we have $W \nsubseteq W_{j-1}$ so we can find $w \in W \cap (W_j \setminus W_{j-1})$. Such $w$ has the form

$$ w = a_1 e_1 + \dots + a_{j-1} e_{j-1} + a_j e_j $$

with $a_j \neq 0$. But then $T^j(w) = a_j e_1$ and since $W$ is $T$-invariant, we see that $e_1 \in W$. Replacing $w$ with $w - a_1 e_1$, we see that

$$ T^{j-1}(w - a_1e_1) = T^{j-1}(a_2e_2 + \dots + a_j e_j) = a_j e_2 $$

and so $e_2 \in W$. Repeating the argument, we get that $e_1,\dots,e_{j-1} \in W$ and then

$$ e_j = \frac{w - a_1 e_1 - \dots - a_{j-1} e_{j-1}}{a_j} \in W$$
showing that $W = W_j$.

Comment: Do you assume that $W_n = V$?

Comment: Otherwise the defination of $j$ wouldn't make much of sense if we assume that $k <n$.For instance if we take $V=\mathbb R^2$ and Take $T$ to be the rotation through an angle $\pi$ then every subspace of $V$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ but the straight line $y=x$ doesn't contain in $W_k$ for $k <2$.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay: I don't assume that $W_n = V$, it is actually the case according to your definition. That's why $j$ is well-defined (the set $\{ k \, | \, W \subseteq W_k \}$ is not empty because it contains $n$). Also, $W_0 = \{ 0_V \}$.

Comment: Oh! I have understood.Thanks.